# Graph API Extended Properties AAD and adal.js

Tags: adal, extended-properties, adal.js

WE have gone ahead and used AAD Graph API to extend certain properties of user object which are our primary identifiers.
we use **JWT** token on the client side in  an single page application using adal-angular.
I would like to know to how do you retrieve the custom property added on user to the client side?
**adal.js** brings down a profile property down to the client side which is **$scope.userInfo.** 
Is there any way to make the extended property we created to be available on this property?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me  to get a complete profile after getting authenticated which is giving the profile i desire with extended properties